# Catch error in scheduled batch

Tags: batch, schedulebatch, try-catch

I want to catch here an error on deleting records. but i dont really understand how? Can u help me please?

```
public with sharing class AccountTest implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
  private String query;
  private String standardQuery = 'Select id from Account';
  Exception[] errors = new Exception[0];

  public AccountTest(String query) {
    this.query= query; 
  }
  public AccountTest() {
    this.batchQuery = standardQuery;
  }

  public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
  }
  public void execute(
    
    Database.BatchableContext context,
    List<Account> acc;
  ) {
    try {      
      
      delete acc;
    } catch(Exception e) {
      errors.add(e);
  }
    }
  
  public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    if(!errors.isEmpty()) {
      System.debug('ERROR'+errors);

  }
  }  
}
```

Schedulable class

```
public with sharing class SchedulableAcc implements Schedulable {
    public static final string SCHEDULE_JOB = 'AccJob';

    public void execute(SchedulableContext SC){
        Database.executeBatch(new AccountTest(), 100);
        start();
       
    }

    public static void start(){
        Datetime time = System.now().addSeconds( 20 );
        String yetTime = '' + sysTime.second() + ' ' + sysTime.minute() + ' ' + sysTime.hour() + ' ' + sysTime.day() + ' ' + sysTime.month() + ' ? ' + sysTime.year();
        System.schedule(SCHEDULE_JOB + time , yetTime , new SchedulableAcc());

    }


}
```

Comment: You could use `Database.delete` passing all-in-one as false and process the error results instead of using try/catch.

Comment: @PhilW thanks,i will try.

Comment: why are you querying asyncapexjob and crontrigger ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally to handle errors from batches, you have 2 options:

1. Your `Batchable` class should implement [`Database.Stateful`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_interface.htm) interface to maintain a state of instance member variables between separate chunk's transactions. Also, you should create an inner class to capture the context and errors keeping them in a stateful `jobErrors` field. Example:

```java
public with sharing class AccountTest implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,
 Database.Stateful {
    private String query;
    private List<JobError> jobErrors = new List<JobError>();

    public AccountTest(String query) {
        this.query = query; 
    }

    public Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(this.query);
    }

    public void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, List<Account> accs) {
        try {
            delete accs;
        } catch(Exception e) {
            JobError jobError = new JobError();
            jobError.records = accs;
            jobError.message = e.getMessage();
            jobErrors.add(jobError);
        }
    }

    public void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        // Process job errors
        System.debug('ERRORS '+ jobErrors);
    }

    public class JobError {
        public String message;      
        public List<Account> records;
    }
}
```

2. Your `Batchable` class should implement [`Database.RaisesPlatformEvents`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_batch_platformevents.htm) to fire a platform event:

```java
public with sharing class AccountTest implements Database.Batchable<SObject>,
 Database.RaisesPlatformEvents{
...
}
```

Subscribe to the [`BatchApexErrorEvent`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.platform_events.meta/platform_events/platform_events_subscribe_apex.htm) via an Apex Trigger:

```java
trigger SomeBatchApexErrorEventTrigger on BatchApexErrorEvent (after insert) {
    Set<Id> asyncApexJobIds = new Set<Id>();
    for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt:Trigger.new){
        asyncApexJobIds.add(evt.AsyncApexJobId);
    }
   
    Map<Id,AsyncApexJob> jobs = new Map<Id,AsyncApexJob>(
        [SELECT id, ApexClass.Name FROM AsyncApexJob WHERE Id IN :asyncApexJobIds]
    );
    
    List<JobError> jobErrors = new List<JobError>();
    for(BatchApexErrorEvent evt : Trigger.new) {
        // Only handle events for the job(s) we care about
        if(jobs.get(evt.AsyncApexJobId).ApexClass.Name == 'AccountTest'){
            JobError jobError = new JobError();
            jobError.recordsIds = evt.JobScope.split(',');
            jobError.message = evt.Message;
            jobErrors.add(jobError); 
        }
    }
    // Process job errors fired 
    System.debug('ERRORS '+ jobErrors);
    public class JobError {
        public String message;      
        public List<String> recordsIds;
    }
}
```